Create a UGRID-compliant 3D deformed grid NetCDF file (in Python) to be read by QGIS
My data consists of four 200 x 200 x 50 tensors,

xgrid: E-W coordinates
ygrid: N-S coordinates
zgrid: Depth coordinates
scalar_field: A scalar field array.

The scalar field array represents values defined for cell volumes.
All three grids have local index deformations such that they cannot be easily regridded onto a regular grid; the full x,y,z tensors are needed to define both vertex and cell volumes.
I would like to write a Python script to export these data into a NetCDF file, preferrably using UGRID conventions, so that I can then read and share a QGIS compatible mesh file. I have searched the UGRID, MDAL, and gridded documentation extensively, but I am still confused how to do this.
I've also tried several ways of preparing the .nc file, for example:

import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

nz, ny, nx = xgrid.shape

# separate loading of coordinates
xgrid = ...
ygrid = ...
zgrid = ...
# load scalar values
scalar_values = ...

ds = xr.Dataset(
    {
        "scalar_value": (["z", "y", "x"], scalar_values),
        "mesh2d": xr.DataArray(
            attrs={
                "cf_role": "mesh_topology",
                "long_name": "Mesh topology",
                "topology_dimension": 2,
                "node_coordinates": "node_x node_y",
                "face_node_connectivity": "face_nodes",
            }
        ),
    },
    coords={
        "z": ("z", np.arange(nz)),
        "y": ("y", np.arange(ny)),
        "x": ("x", np.arange(nx)),
        "node_x": (["z", "y", "x"], xgrid),
        "node_y": (["z", "y", "x"], ygrid),
        "node_z": (["z", "y", "x"], zgrid),
    },
    attrs={
        "Conventions": "CF-1.8 UGRID-1.0",
        "title": "3D Volume Data - Logically Rectilinear but X-Y-Z Index Deformed",
    }
)

face_nodes = np.array([
    [i + j*nx, i+1 + j*nx, i+1 + (j+1)*nx, i + (j+1)*nx]
    for j in range(ny-1) for i in range(nx-1)
]).reshape(-1, 4)

ds['face_nodes'] = (["face", "node_per_face"], face_nodes)
ds.face_nodes.attrs["start_index"] = 0

ds.resistivity.attrs.update({
    "long_name": "scalar_value",
    "units": "scalar units",
    "mesh": "mesh2d",
    "location": "face",
})

ds.to_netcdf("volume_data_3d_deformed_ugrid.nc")

The resulting NetCDF file when imported to QGIS shows a regular, rectangular grid, with little resemblance to what I know the scalar field to be.
Given my data, how do I make my .nc file QGIS-compatible?
